# Using BackgroundWorker WPF and getting error: Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am fairly new to multi threading, therefore please excuse any obvious mistakes which may be present - I am still learning!

I currently have a program which reads in from a port using `TCPClient` and `NetworkStream` and outputs the data to a `text box` in a WPF program. Nonetheless, when trying to read in multiple times from the `stream`, it slows the program down quite noticeably and the more it has to read, the longer it takes for the program to open. Therefore I decided to try and implement `threading` and I am trying to use `Background Worker`.

Here is the code I have in the `MainWindow`:

```
InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        client.Connect(address, port); //connect to the client 
        nwStream = client.GetStream(); //read in data from stream
        readInTxtBox.Text = ("Connection Open");
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker(); 

        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork; 
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        readInTxtBox.Text = ex.ToString(); //write out the error
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Close();
    }
```

This is the `worker_DoWork` and `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` methods:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        ReadIn();
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ReadIn();
        }));
    }
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        OutputToTextBoxInput();

    }));

}
```

When stepping through, it does go to the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` action on the `worker_DoWork`, and fails on the first line of the `ReadIn()` method :

```
private void ReadIn()
{
    byte[] b = Utilities.ReadInBytes(client, nwStream); //fails here!
    hex = Utilities.ConvertByteToHex(b);
    nwStream.Close();
}
```

It `fails` on the following line of the `ReadInBytes` method, with the error: `Cannot access a disposed object.`

```
public static byte[] ReadInBytes(TcpClient client, NetworkStream nwStream)
{
    byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize]; //FAILS HERE
    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);

    return segment.ToArray();
}
```

The `client` and `network stream` are declared as `public statics`. I have had this problem when using `invoke` and when not. I have also tried `BeginInvoke` and the same problem has occurred.
Any help would be massively appreciated as well as any explanations on where I have gone wrong!

Comment: Why do you dispatching `ReadIn`? If you want to run it on the GUI thread, it makes no sense to use a `BackgroundWorker`... ;)

Comment: It seemed really slow when it was running on the GUI thread

Comment: Actually I would excpect that the code above is even slower :P

Comment: Ah okay, what approach do you think would be most suitable? The idea is I want to loop the ReadIn() method to read in multiple times from the stream as the data coming from the port is continous. That is why I felt having a different thread from the GUI would be more appropriate so it wouldn't slow down other processes.

Comment: use a `long-running` `Task`, not the background worker`, with only dispatching the UI-related code. `BackgroundWorker` is such an outdated and potentially dangerous approach.

Comment: @VMAtm: you are right, it is better to use tasks here (probably not a long-running because ReadIn seems to be a short operation) - however background workers are still OK IMHO - why do you think they are potentially dangerous?

Comment: Because people usually start a lot of them, and, as this approach related to opening a new thread for each worker, this leads to system performance issues. People just don't understand what they are doing. And the lower is the API they used, the more harm they are doing to the applications they write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you dispose the client in the finally block, but use it in the `DoWork` methods which is running later.

To solve it, create, connect and clode the client in the DoWork event :).

---

As mentioned in a comment, you should not dispatch your code in the DoWork method! Just call ReadIn there. You want to run the code in background, so that the GUI remains resposable - it makes no sense to push it to the GUI thread!

It is also not required to dispatch the code in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, because the background work does it for you ;).

Comment: Perfect thank you! Quite annoyed at myself for not trying that haha :)

Comment: Note that any access to GUI controls (e.g. `readInTxtBox.Text = ("Connection Open");`) have to be dispatched in method  `DoWork`.